# Android TextView span full width programmatically

Tags: android, textview, width

I've created a TextView within a LinearLayout programmatically:

```
LinearLayout filmTitleContainer = new LinearLayout(ctx);
TextView filmName = new TextView(ctx);
filmName.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(Color.YELLOW));
filmName.setText(this.screeningTime+" "+this.name);
```

The text view is shrunk:

[image]

How do I set the text to the occupy the full width of the screen? When I use the XML layout file, I'd set `android:layout_width="match_parent"`. What's the equivalent Java code?

---

Comment: Please mind your tag selection.  I'm not sure how you butchered "android" into "adnrdoi"...

Answer (score 16):

Use `LayoutParams` for both the view and its container:

```
LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f);
filmTitleContainer.setLayoutParams(params);
filmName.setLayoutParams(params);
```

[image]